# Laravel - Load only five games per user

Tags: laravel

I have a table structure as follows:

users

- id
- name
- email
- password

games

- id
- title

And the pivot table:

game_user

- id
- score
- game_id
- user_id

Now the User model is defined like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function games() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class);
    }
}
```

Now, what I'm interested in doing is write a single Eloquent expression that will get me an array of users, with each having at most five games. Doing something like `User::with('games')->get()` of course fetches all the games for every user.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use `take()` method:

```
   User::with(['games'=>function($query){
          if($query->count()>5)
            {
                $query->take(5);
            }
            else
            {
                $query->get();
            }
    }])->get();
```

There is no easy way to acheive this. See [Tweaking Eloquent Relations](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/).

Comment: I have six games for user1 and two for user2 in my DB. Your solution is loading five for user1 and none for user2. Do you want me to share the DB details and final output?

Comment: @dotslash you can count the number of games. If greater than 5 take 5, else take all. updated the answer.